# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'api link' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I'm facing a strange CORS issue in NodeJS+React application.
For some reason i'm getting the following error for **specific api request** while all the others work well:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/airports/addchart' from origin 'https://dashboard.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

For demostration there is no error for this route:
https://api.example.com/airports/addrunway.

In addition, I've checked million times already that the api request address is correct.

The api request in the REACT application:

```
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        "runwayid": runway,
        "name": name,
        "link": link,
        "airportid": details.airport._id,
        "type": type
    });

    var config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: process.env.API + '/airports/addchart',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        data: data
    };

    axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            alert(response.data);
            handleClose();
            setIsLoading(true);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

}
```

What could be the reason for this CORS issue?

Comment: use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: I use CORS for the entire nodejs app (app.use(cors());

Comment: Are the API which throws CORS error only the POST method ? What is the difference between error API and working correctly API ? Is there a difference in code structures ?

Comment: That's the point - there is no difference at all between them.
For demostration: 
https://api.example.com/airports/addchart - Not working.
https://api.example.com/airports/addrunway - Working.
They are both POST requests, and they are both being called from the same location (https://dashboard.example.com).
And I used app.use(cors()) in the main JS js (where the app.listen is).

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this in the header:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: added like this but still the same....
        var config = {
            method: 'post',
            url: process.env.API + '/airports/addchart',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
            data: data
        };